# Fixing tab and space inconsistency

Tags: indentation, visual-mode, tab-characters

I used `<` in visual model to do a shift+tab reverse for a code inside loop after I removed the try/except phrase. Now, I get an error:

```
$ python clean_captions.py 
  File "clean_captions.py", line 157
    split = get_split()
                      ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Is there an automated way in vim or command line in Linux to fix this? I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It might be helpful if you [edit] to include what's wrong and how you want to change it: are there tabs that need to be spaces? vice-versa? how many? Even sample input/output will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurred because there is an inconsistency between the spaces and tabs used for indentation in your code. You have probably opened a tab indented code, and started editing it, while vim was set to indent using spaces.
To solve this issue, first, set your tabbing space setting in your `~/.vim/vimrc` by

```
set softtabstop=4
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

Then, use `:retab` to fix the indentation issue in your code.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It might help the OP and others if you explain how this helps fix the problem.

Comment: just `:retab` works for me

Comment: `:retab` did not work for me. I needed to force convert all spaces to tabs. I had to use `:%retab!`